# Change play button to pause on click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

i am building app with Xcode 11 Swift and i want to add mp3 file in my app and so far i have done this

[image]

but i want to show just one button like when user click on play button pause button should display and vice versa, how can i get this ? this is my code to play mp3 file

```
 @IBAction func Play(_sender: Any) {
           player.play()
 }

 @IBAction func Stop(_sender: Any) {
           player.stop()
 }

let audioPlayer = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "chalisa", ofType: "mp3")
try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPlayer!)) as URL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one function:

```
// Note: you should change sender type
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if player.isPlaying {
        player.stop()
        sender.setImage(yourPlayImage, for: .normal)
    } else {
        player.play()
        sender.setImage(yourPauseImage, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this change the button when it is pressed?

Comment: @koen Fixed it.

Comment: how to insert play or pause image ? when i try to add play or pause image name error occured

Comment: @ChandNinder What's the error? Where do you create play/pause images? Did you rename the sender type?

Comment: i got it now problem is that there should be play button display for default, when i open the viewcontroller no play button shows up and when i click on the space where i have added button then pause button shows and vice versa

Comment: @ChandNinder How did you add the default button image?

Comment: in viewController i have added Button that shows up as Play icon but when i click on it pause button shows up inside of Play icon and when i click on pause play button display in play button, i want to remove play button in ViewController and want to show it from code that you sent

Comment: @ChandNinder My code changes the button image on click. If the button has a play image, it will have a pause image. And vice versa.

You should add some code that shows how you implemented it. My code should work if you correctly linked the `buttonPressed` function with the button in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the state of the player (or ask from it if you are ok with that). Then update the button based on the state:

```
enum PlayerState {
    case playing
    case stopped

    mutating func toggle() {
        switch self {
        case .playing: self = .stopped
        case .stopped: self = .playing
        }
    }
}

var state = PlayerState.stopped {
    didSet {
        switch state {
        case .playing: player.play()
        case .stopped: player.stop()
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonDidTouch(_ sender: Any) { state.toggle() }
```